# how to use state of one component in another component ? Independent components (React)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using a checkbox menu in my dropdown component when the user check any option from the dropdown check box then the state is updated and this is working fine now i want to use that state into my other component how can i do that i know redux is used to communicate between siblings but i am facing trouble
here is my dropdown code

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const options1 = [
  {label: 'One', value: 1},
  {label: 'Two', value: 2},
  {label: 'Three', value: 3},
];
class _Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
    };
    this.selected = this.selected.bind(this);
  }
  selected = (selected) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({selected}, () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        recent_slected_user_accountsid + 'selected zones_ID',
        this.state.selected,
      );
      sessionStorage.setItem('zoneflag', 1);
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MultiSelect
          onSelectedChanged={this.selected}
          options={options}
          selected={this.state.selected}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      age: state.age
    };
  };
  const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onAgeUp: () => dispatch({ type: "AGE_UP", value: new _Dropdown().state.selected}), 
// how can i pass selected state to this dispatch function because i am trying to use state outside a component
      onAgeDown: () => dispatch({ type: "AGE_DOWN", value: "raza"})
    };
  };
// export default _Dropdown
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispachToProps
  )(_Dropdown);
```

this is my reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  age: "raza"
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AGE_UP":
      newState.age = action.value;
      break;
    case "AGE_DOWN":
      newState.age = action.value;
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};
export default reducer;
```

this is my index.js

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../app/routes/Meep/store/reducer';
const store = createStore(reducer);
render(
<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

now i want to use that selected state in my other component how can i do that ? if already tried this by using react Redux BUT I am facing trouble how to pass that state in dispatch function ? can anyone help me how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you reformat you code please ? This is really hard to read like this...

Comment: Post your full code, including your redux reducer/actions.

Comment: Why would you couple this to redux (or session storage)? Typically a control like this would just expose callbacks like `onChange`.

Comment: Yup @jonrsharpe is right, this has nothing to do with redux or any state management library. You can do this with prop drilling or context API. OP should also understand how props are being passed in React.

Comment: i updated the code sir ... i am using redux because i want to intialized that selected state globally in redux store then i use this anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling dispatch function on a wrong place . pls call dispatch where you want to update state in you case call dispatch in selected function because you are updating your state there which you want to send to reducer ... you will look like this

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const options1 = [
  {label: 'One', value: 1},
  {label: 'Two', value: 2},
  {label: 'Three', value: 3},
];
class _Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
    };
    this.selected = this.selected.bind(this);
  }
  selected = (selected) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({selected}, () => {
     
 this.props.dispatch({type: "AGE_UP", value:this.state.selected})
 sessionStorage.setItem(
        recent_slected_user_accountsid + 'selected zones_ID',
        this.state.selected,
      );
      sessionStorage.setItem('zoneflag', 1);
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MultiSelect
          onSelectedChanged={this.selected}
          options={options}
          selected={this.state.selected}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      age: state.age
    };
  };

// export default _Dropdown
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,

  )(_Dropdown);
```

and if you want to use that state in some other class you can easily do this like this

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return(<div>
your age : {this.props.age}

</div>)
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      age: state.age,
    
    };
  };

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  
  )(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You can't use the state of a component in another, unless the other component is a direct child. You need to use a different approach to share data (like Redux).

---

Long answer:

By definition, component state represents the internal data required by the component to work. It is not meant to be shared across other components (except its children: you can pass a state variable as a child component's prop).

If you want to share data across different, non-related components, you have essentially two options:

1. You put the data somewhere else, on a upper level. This is the Redux approach.
2. You create event handlers on you component to trigger something outside of the component, which will be responsible of dispatching the data wherever it needs to be sent.

Here is what option 2 would look like with your code as a starting point:

```js
class _Dropdown extends React.Component {
    // _Dropdown takes in a new prop: onSelectionChanged
    constructor(props) {
        /* Same as yours */
    }
    
    selected = (selected) => {
        // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
        this.setState({selected}, () => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(recent_slected_user_accountsid + 'selected zones_ID', this.state.selected)
            sessionStorage.setItem('zoneflag', 1)
        })
    
        // Add this
        if (this.onSelectionChanged) {
            this.onSelectionChanged(selected);
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        /* Same as yours */
    }
}
```